# do Hindu scriptures talk about which relatives you may marry?

Tags: marriage

In Southern India, Hindus can marry first cousins - in other words you and your wife may have the same grandparents.  Also girls can marry their uncle - mother's brother.  Obviously the law sanctions this - but how about Hindu scripture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they definitely talk about the girls who are fit to marry and about those who are not fit.

See the following verses:

> A householder should marry a wife who comes from the same class as
>   he, who has not been married before, and who is younger than he.  **A
>   marriage can be contracted only between persons not belonging to a
>   family with the same ancestral seer   and not related within six
>   degrees on the side of the legal  or the biological father , or within
>   four degrees on the mother’s side.**
>
> **Gautama Smriti 3.24**

> Householder––after bringing his anger and excitement final bath with
>   the permission of his teacher, he should select for his wife a woman
>   who does not belong to a lineage with the same ancestral seer who has
>   not experienced sex before, who is younger than he and belongs to the
>   same class as he, and who is not related within four degrees on the
>   mother’s side or six degrees on the father’s side. He should kindle
>   the nuptial fire.
>
> **Vashishta Dharma Sutras 7.3**

As regards, the practice followed in South India, Baudhayana says the following:

> There are five areas in which the practices of the south and the north
>   differ from each other . We will explain the ones peculiar to the
>   south.
>
> They are: eating in the company of an uninitiated person, eating in
>   the company of one’s wife, eating stale food, and marrying the
>   daughter of the mother’s brother or the father’s sister.
>
> The ones peculiar to the north are: selling wool, drinking rum,
>   trafficking in animals with teeth in both jaws, making a living as a
>   soldier, and travelling by sea.  If a man follows the practices of the
>   former in the latter, and those of the latter in the former, he
>   becomes defiled. Each practice is based solely on the authority of the
>   customs of that region.
>
> That is untrue, say Gautama.  A man should
>   pay heed to neither set of practices, because they are shown to be
>   opposed to the tradition of cultured people.
>
> **Baudhayana Dharma Sutras 1.2.3**

Comment: Baidhyana was South indian?

Comment: Some say both Apasthambha and Baudhayana were South Indians.. but i can not say for sure.. @AnubhavJha

Comment: after rig veda hinduism is largely South Indian and Bengali

Comment: What does that mean? @SK Other Dharma Shastra Kartas are all from northern India.. Only those two are exceptions AFAIK.. Also, there are no connections between Bengal and South India.. BTW if i am not wrong u urself is also a South Indian?

Comment: @SK Also i have answered ur Q comprehensively.. u now know the answer..

Comment: What is obvious? I am not getting ur point.. anyways what more do u need in the answer? @SK